# extracting &lt and &gt from html using python

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML in UTF-8 encoding like below. I want to extract OWNER, NVCODE, CKHEWAT tags from this using python and bs4. But <> is converted to &lt and &gt I am not able to extract text from OWNER, NVCODE, CKHEWAT tags.

kindly guide me to extract text from these tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><html><body><string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">&lt;root&gt;&lt;OWNER&gt;अराजी मतरुका   वासीदेह &lt;/OWNER&gt;&lt;NVCODE&gt;00108&lt;/NVCODE&gt;&lt;CKHEWAT&gt;811&lt;/CKHEWAT&gt;&lt;/root&gt;</string></body></html>
```

My code

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
soup.find('string').text
```

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Can you provide the source url?

Answer (score 1):

[Check this](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters)

By default, the only characters that are escaped upon output are bare ampersands and angle brackets. These get turned into “&”, “<”, and “>”, so that Beautiful Soup doesn’t inadvertently generate invalid HTML or XML:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>The law firm of Dewey, Cheatem, & Howe</p>")
soup.p
# <p>The law firm of Dewey, Cheatem, &amp; Howe</p>

soup = BeautifulSoup('<a href="http://example.com/?foo=val1&bar=val2">A link</a>')
soup.a
# <a href="http://example.com/?foo=val1&amp;bar=val2">A link</a>
```

You can change this behavior by providing a value for the formatter argument to prettify(), encode(), or decode(). Beautiful Soup recognizes six possible values for formatter.

The default is formatter="minimal". Strings will only be processed enough to ensure that Beautiful Soup generates valid HTML/XML:

```py
french = "<p>Il a dit &lt;&lt;Sacr&eacute; bleu!&gt;&gt;</p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(french)
print(soup.prettify(formatter="minimal"))
# <html>
#  <body>
#   <p>
#    Il a dit &lt;&lt;Sacré bleu!&gt;&gt;
#   </p>
#  </body>
# </html>
```

Comment: @ Iakovos Belonias.... Thanks for the help but you solution is not working....I have modified my question. response from beautiful soup includes <body> and <html> tags.